# Google App Engine with Cloud SQL Deploy Error Using Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, sequelize.js, google-cloud-sql

I want to deploy my node app to app engine and use cloud sql mysql with Sequelize for the ORM, however i get the below error on deployment, with no further info to debug.

my yaml is (with redacted details):

```
env: flex
runtime: nodejs
env_variables:
  SQL_USER: -
  SQL_PASSWORD: -
  SQL_DATABASE: -
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: -

  beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: -
```

> Unable to connect to SQL database: undefined
>   Uncaught Error { filename:
>      '/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js',
>     line: 133,
>     row: 19,
>     message: 'connect ENOENT /cloudsql/app:europe-west1:db',
>     type: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
>     stack:
>      'SequelizeConnectionError: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/app:europe-west1:db\n    at Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:133:19)\n    at tryCatcher (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)\n    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)\n    at Promise._settlePromise (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)\n    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)\n    at Promise._settlePromises (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:690:18)\n    at _drainQueueStep (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)\n    at _drainQueue (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)\n    at Async._drainQueues (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:147:5)\n    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/app/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)\n    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)\n    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)\n    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)',
>     arguments: undefined }

The ORM code:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
      dialect: 'mysql',
      host: '/cloudsql/app:europe-west1:db',
      pool: {
          max: 5,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000
      },
      dialectOptions: {
          socketPath: '/cloudsql/app:europe-west1:db'
      },
      logging: false
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `app.yaml` shouldn't have `beta_settings:` indented:

```
...
  INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: <YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

Next, the unix socket is at `/cloudsql/<YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`. You should use the environment variable you specified in your `app.yaml` to set this programmatically:

```
socketPath: util.format('/cloudsql/%s', process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME), // '/cloudsql/<YOUR_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>`
```

You also specify `SQL_USER`, `SQL_PASSWORD`, `SQL_DATABASE` as env vars in your `app.yaml`, but call `process.env.DB_USER`, `process.env.DB_PASS`, `process.env.DB_NAME`. They need to be consistent if you want them to have any values.

Finally, Sequelize is somewhat unclear on how best to use a unix socket - `host` and `dialectOptions.socketPath` probably shouldn't both be set. Judging from the [Sequelize docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/usage.html), I would suggest just using `socketPath`:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASS, {
      dialect: 'mysql',
      pool: {
          max: 5,
          min: 0,
          acquire: 30000,
          idle: 10000
      },
      dialectOptions: {
          socketPath: util.format('/cloudsql/%s', process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME),
      },
      logging: false
    });
```

Comment: thanks seems to be past these errors now, getting `(gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] ` but assume thats a different issue

Comment: @jwarris91 Sorry, but without more of the error you are encountering I can't provide any suggestions. It appears to be a problem with the deployment itself rather than the connection to Cloud SQL. 

If the above answer was helpful to you, please make sure to upvote or accept it so others can more easily evaluate for their own needs.